# What does $d \| \vec{x} \|$ represent?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am doing some review problems for my upcoming exam and something has come up that I don't understand.

$$\int_{\gamma} f(x,y) \space d \|\vec{x} \|$$

$\gamma(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$

$f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$

$t \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}], \space \text{and} \space x,y \space \in\Bbb R^2 \text{/}(0,0)$

What does $d \|  \vec{x} \|$ represent? I have never seen absolute values around a differential.

Comment: The best guess I an make is that it means integral wrt arc length.

Comment: Also, the curve is missing a parameter domain, making the question ill-posed.

Comment: @ncmathsadist Sorry I forgot that. I will add it to the question.

Comment: I think it's a typo. The symbol $d\| \vec x\|$ should be replaced by $\|d\vec x\|$. Note that $d\| \vec x\|\equiv0$ along $\gamma$, which would make the problem trivial.

Comment: @Christian Blatter Danke! That sounds reasonable. But what would $\lvert \lvert d\vec{x} \rvert \rvert$ look like in my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition 
$$\lvert \lvert \vec{x} \rvert \rvert = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$
You have a parametrization of $\gamma$ with respect to $t$. This means we have functions $x(t), y(t)$ and we can write the integral in terms of them with
$$d\lvert \lvert \vec{x} \rvert \rvert = \frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{x(t)^2 + y(t)^2}dt$$

So if the parametrization covers $[t_0, t_1]$ then your integral is
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} f(x(t), y(t)) \frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{x(t)^2 + y(t)^2}dt$$

Alternatively you could take this as the definition
$$d\lvert \lvert \vec{x} \rvert \rvert = \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$

That would yield:
$$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} f(x(t), y(t)) \sqrt{\left(\frac{dx(t)}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy(t)}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$

Comment: So in this case I interpret $\gamma(t)$ as a position vector $\vec{x}$?

Comment: Yes, although you know it is because it is given in parametrized form as $(cos(t), sin(t))$

Comment: Also, wouldn't the integral become zero since:

$$\frac{d}{dt} \sqrt{x(t)^2+y(t)^2}=\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)}=\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{1}=0$$

Comment: or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: That would be correct.  This is all guessing since it's non standard notation.  It could also be with respect to arc-length.  I'll add that in there.

Comment: Looking at the other questions I have done I think the second option is correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: .Happy to help.